# SWRevealViewController is getting nil after returning back through segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

In loginVC i have created a button on clicking it, it goes to main tabbarcontroller thru segue like this..

```
@IBAction func btnLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("logintoMain", sender: self)    
}
```

is succesfully goes to tabbarmainVC but after that the swRevealviewController is getting nil.. and the sliding not working here. why?

```
class MaintabbarController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var slideBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if self.revealViewController() != nil{
        slideBtn.target = self.revealViewController()
        slideBtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }    
}
```

**Edited**

I have tried this code also on login button click to go to the mainTabbarvc. Now its working fine . Actually i have to push the revealviewController than only it will be active..

```
 @IBAction func btnLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
  let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let vc =sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourtabbarvcidentifier") as! UITabBarController
   vc.selectedIndex = 0
 // self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
  }
```

Comment: Did you configure your storyBoard to work with SWRevealViewController properly? I mean sw_front segue identifier, sw_rear  segue identifier etc?

Comment: yes all are correctly working . only problem came afterreturmimg back to this page thru segue on clicking any button of viewcontroller@ReinierMelian

Answer (score 1):

Try adding it to this function and see what happens:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if self.revealViewController() != nil{
    slideBtn.target = self.revealViewController()
    slideBtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
 }
}
```

This will appear when the view is active.

Comment: still getting the same issue. i set the breakpoints there and checked . it checks for the swrevealviewController and gets nil.. thats why not going under if condition

Comment: have you given the view controller your using the SWRevealViewController class?

Comment: m using SWRevealViewController class from github

Comment: Is it looking like this in your storyboard: http://i.imgur.com/rH8eb8A.png

Comment: yeah i am using the storyboard

Comment: so you've set the UIViewControllers class as SWRevealViewController?

Comment: but the class should be swrevealviewController there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117341/discussion-between-pradip-kumar-and-konsy).